# UITableView Autoresizing does not work in preview for iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

In the above design the Autoresizing is configured correctly.

+0 from bottom , top ,left and right for the `UITableView`.

+8 from bottom , top ,left and right (The Green Color View)

But the preview looks like this.
[image]

Comment: What version of xcode do you use and is this happening to the others iphones too? Did you try to run it on simulator to see if is the same with the preview (try also to add center vertical and horizontal in container)

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.2.1. When I use other iPhone simulator it shows correctly in Preview. Maybe the preview is not compatible with iPhone 4s as when I launch the Simulator it shows correctly. Could be a bug in Preview part.